# Why do convolutional neural networks use so much memory?

Tags: memory, machine-learning, neural-networks

I heard that one of the main problems applying [neural style](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) to high resolution images is the huge amount of memory that would use.

Also I just [configured](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/f9607d62fb2ec289e94f3330e5771e30) a network using [tiny-cnn](https://github.com/nyanp/tiny-cnn)

This is my calculation for number of weights and number of neurons per layer in my example:

```
conv_layer_# height width depth filter_height filter_width neurons_(h*w*d) weights
1            512    512   3     3             3            786432          108    
2            256    256   6     3             3            393216          216    
3            128    128   12    3             3            196608          432    
4            64     64    24    3             3            98304           864    
5            32     32    48    3             3            49152           1728   
6            16     16    96    3             3            24576           3456   
7            8      8     192   3             3            12288           6912   

                                                           1560576         13716
```

If we give every value that has to be stored 8 bytes (single precision floating point format), we end up with 6297168 bytes, i.e. about 12 MB. But the net allocates over 1GB of RAM when I train it. What is all that memory needed for?

Comment: Aren't there a hundred millionish synapses in your configuration?

Comment: Are you aware that a neural network needs to store the state of every single neuron and every single synapse somewhere?

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, I am aware of this. I added my calculation of number of neurons and weights to my question.

Comment: @TobiasHermann 4 bytes? Really? With 4 bytes you can't even *find* the neuron you're looking for on a 64-bit OS, let alone store data about it.

Comment: @Ordous: Why should I need pointers to single neurons? Or why should a neuron need more than one single floating point value?

Comment: @TobiasHermann You either need to know which neuron connects to which, or if your layers are fully connected to the next layer, then you need weights for each input neuron in each neuron you have.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about a convolutional network. As far as I understand the connection betweens the neurons are fixed due to the dimensions of the layers and filters, and thus need not to be saved explicitly.

Comment: @TobiasHermann: to index 700k neurons, you need at least 24-bit pointers / indexes; realistically it's 32-bit pointers / indexes. So every synapse has to spend 4 bytes just to point to the neuron it connects to, along with at least 2 bytes for the connection weight.

Comment: @9000: I do not see why the neurons have to be indexed. I would think the layer volumes are a simple multidimensional array in memory, but OK. Even when including your pointers, the calculated memory is still two orders of magnitude smaller compared to what really seems to happen in the system.

Comment: @TobiasHermann: Well, let's suppose that the CNN is packaged in the most optimal way. What kind of allocations can ever happen when it's being trained? If allocations occur, there may just be a space leak.

Comment: OK, this would point to a problem with tiny-cnn only. But the mentioned "neural style" uses a different backend (torch).

Comment: Does tiny-cnn come with source code?  Seems like it would be a relatively straightforward exercise to find out where it's using memory if you have a debugger and a profiler.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good hint, thank you. [Using valgrind](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/76baee65803d6267721adc21dd21c7d9) I found [the function in the code that allocates a good chunk of all that memory](https://github.com/nyanp/tiny-cnn/blob/aa71c81e71102f1a495ca95e7243d64779252831/tiny_cnn/network.h#L824). Now I only have to understand what this means on a higher level. ;)

Comment: @TobiasHermann Do post a self-answer when you find out, even if it turns out to be library-specific. I'm curious by now as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out some of the factors that may contribute to the effect.

1) At least in tiny-cnn, some of the buffers are allocated not once but once per **worker thread**. On a machine with **8** CPU threads, this can increase the memory usage a lot.
In debug mode using MS VC++ 2015 the following two lines in the code base allocate a big chunk, both related to worker threads: [`ith_in_node(i)->set_worker_size(worker_count);`](https://github.com/nyanp/tiny-cnn/blob/aa71c81e71102f1a495ca95e7243d64779252831/tiny_cnn/layers/layer.h#L481) and [`ith_out_node(i)->set_worker_size(worker_count);`](https://github.com/nyanp/tiny-cnn/blob/aa71c81e71102f1a495ca95e7243d64779252831/tiny_cnn/layers/layer.h#L485).

2) Additionally to the values for the neurons and weights listed in my question, also gradients and some other stuff for the backward passes and the optimization have to be stored.

3) Not sure if this is relevant fot tiny-cnn, but many frameworks seem to use an operation called **im2col**. This makes the convolution much faster, by expressing it as a matrix multiplication. But in case of filters with 3*3 in height and width, this scales the number of values from the input to a convolution up by a factor of **9**.
Justin Johnson explains it in the lecture ["S231n Winter 2016 Lecture 11 ConvNets in practice"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue4RJdI8yRA) starting at 36:22.

4) There was an **error in my initial calculation**. When a volume of 512*512*3 is convolved with 6 3*3 filters and then send into an average pooling layer, the result volume is 256*256*6, but in between it is 512*512*6, also contributing with a factor of **2**.

5) There was **another error in my initial calculation**. I demonstrate it on the last conv layer (7). It takes a volume of 16*16*96 to a volume of 8*8*192 with filters of size 3*3. This means every filter has 3*3*96 weights, and there are 192 of them, resulting in 165888 (3*3*96*192) weights overall for this layer, not 6912.

So numerologically multiplying only the first three factors (8, 9 and 2) we end up with a factor of 144, which seems enough to explain the high memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation for the amount of memory used appears to be related to the number of neurons in the network and storing a `double` for each, but that isn't the only storage that is required -- each neuron will also contain a number of weights, each of which is likely to need at least a `float`.  This is the last column in your output, and (at least if I understand the program you're using correctly) is the number of weights stored *per neuron*.  Assuming each weight is a `float`, this adds up to a little over 2GB.

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through. But the way I understand CNNs the number of weights is not per neuron but per layer. In a convolutional layer the weights are shared, which is different from a fully connected layer. see http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/